# Uploading PhD dissertation to ResearchGate

Tags: phd, thesis, data-sharing

My PhD dissertation has already been uploaded to the [HAL Theses](https://theses.hal.science/) website.

Would it be beneficial to also upload it to ResearchGate?

Comment: What do you mean by beneficial--for you or your readers?

Comment: @Dr. Banjadebaje . For me.

Comment: I am assuming you are done with your dissertation, already been uploaded online, and is openly and freely available. In this case, uploading in Research Gate does not make any difference other than sharing among your network. This is, however, not a significant benefit but it won't hurt to upload. You may significantly benefit by publishing papers from dissertations.

Comment: Look at it this way: uploading takes maybe a couple of minutes at the most and there are no drawbacks. On the other hand, it might increase visibility. So what is keeping you?

Comment: @Sursula One would have to agree to ResearchGate's terms of service, which doesn't necessarily constitute "no drawbacks".